# PHPExcel error when opening downloaded file error "incorrect file format"

Tags: zend-framework

I'm creating an Excel report containing UTF-8 encoded data using PHPExcel on Zend. When  I'm downloading and  trying to open it in Excel it works on local environment but  I'm getting the following Error:  "Incorrect file format" from live sever/production. Any help / references would be appreciated.

here is a code i used to download xls file:

```
public function getCsv($data, $filename = false)
 {
     /**
      * generate a file name using unixTimeStamp
      * @var string $tmpfname
      */
      if ($filename)
      {
          $tmpfile =    "/tmp/".$filename. "-". date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') . ".csv";
          $name = str_replace(' ','',$filename)."-".date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') . ".xls";
      }
      else
      {
          $tmpfile = "/tmp/report". "_". date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') . ".csv";
          $name = "report-".date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') . ".xls";
      }
      /**
       * open Temporary file name in write mode
       * @var object $fp
       */
       $fp = fopen($tmpfile, "w");
       /**
        * foreach datas write to csv
        */
       foreach ($data as $fields)
           fputcsv($fp, $fields, ',', '"');

       /**
        * close file
        */
        fclose($fp);

        try
        {
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($tmpfile);
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

            //set Header Content Type as application/csv
            header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use this line before saving :

```
ob_end_clean();
```